# Why does ogr's CreateLayer() return None?

Tags: gdal, ogr, python-2.7

Why does ogr's driver method `CreateLayer` return `None`? I'm using python 2.7 with gdal 1.9.1.

```
path = r'D:\_tempAuto'
out_shp = '%s\test_OGR.shp' % (path,) 
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource(out_shp)
layer = ds.CreateLayer('test_OGR', geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString)

>>> ds
<osgeo.ogr.DataSource; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDataSourceShadow 
*' at 0x00C71638> >

type(layer)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because GDAL wasn't able to create a layer from the shape file. The offending line:

> out_shp = '%s\test_OGR.shp' % (path,)

You have to escape the slash, like so:

> out_shp = '%s\ \test_OGR.shp' % (path,)

Otherwise, Python would will treat the \test part as \t or tab. Your resulting path would then be:

> D:_tempAuto   est_OGR.shp

hence the empty layer. You could also tell Python to treat it as a raw string by prefixing the string with *r* or *R* like you did with your *path* variable.

Comment: I was a little too quick asking this question. Thanks for answering, anyway. You are absolutely right with your answer. The same affect has putting a `r` before the string, making it "raw" (like I did in the first line). I oversaw this at the second line (if you just look too long at your code...).

Comment: Yeah. Mistakes happen. Sorry if my answer seemed patronizing. Glad to be of help :)

Comment: No man, no worries. Your help is very much appreciated.